# R: Export data frame to SPSS

Tags: r, spss

I have a data frame which I created by importing a .dat Stata file in this manner:

```
data = read.dta("TEAdataSTATA2.dta")
```

I then write `data` to a text file:

```
write.table(b , "mydata.txt" , sep="\t")
```

I then use the text file I created to create an SPSS file in this manner:

```
write.foreign(b , "mydata.txt" , "DerLeew.sps" , package="SPSS")
```

However, I get an error:

```
Error in writeForeignSPSS(df = list(studyid = c("P0008", "P0018", "P0031",  : 
  I cannot abbreviate the variable names to eight or fewer letters
```

Could someone point out the problem?

Comment: Can you edit the results of `names(b)` into your question? It will be helpful to specifically nail down where things are going wrong.

Comment: After looking at Jonathan's answer and the code I think his answer is correct and that your failure to address a fairly specific error message deserves a downvote.

Comment: @BondedDust if you think so, maybe i do deserve it.

Comment: @BondedDust But that check only happens when `is.null(varnames)`. If you supply them, it doesn't check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SPSS used to only support variable names with 8 or less characters. It looks like the code is writing for this older version of SPSS. It attempts to abbreviate the variables to be shorter, but it fails in your case.

Part of the code:

> ```
>  if (is.null(varnames)) {
>      varnames <- abbreviate(names(df), 8)
>      if (any(sapply(varnames, nchar) > 8))
>          stop("I cannot abbreviate the variable names to eight or fewer letters")
>      if (any(varnames != names(df)))
>          warning("some variable names were abbreviated")
>  }
> ```

You may need to rename the variables to be shorter before calling this function, or try to find an implementation that can write the newer formats of SPSS.

Comment: Interesting that the code uses `sapply(...)`  when just `any(nchar(varnames) > 8)` would work.

Answer (score 7):

What if you try

```
foreign:::writeForeignSPSS(b , "mydata.txt" , "DerLeew.sps" , 
    varnames=names(b))
```

It looks like this method will bypass the variable shrinking. Just make sure your version of SPSS can open it.

Comment: It's working fine when exporting the data but unfortunately giving errors for my colleagues while importing into SPSS.